# Need to restrict access to my printer, my kids prints lots of stuff, although some are just long pages?

Tags: windows-xp, printer, parental-controls

I'm looking for way to stop my kid from using up tons of paper and ink.

He prints picture from google images.

He only prints stuff while I'm on my computer, so I guess if I could preview all stuff would be OK, but ideally a number of page restrictions would be the best solution for me.

Any ideas?

This is for a Epson R285 with a HP Wireless Printer Server.

Comment: What printer are you using (manufacturer, model)?

Comment: Epson R285 with a HP Wireless Printer Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either install Print to PDF and set that as default printer, and if your kid does not know to change the printer he will be only producing PDF documents or you can try [PrintLock](http://www.windows7download.com/win7-printlock/cvpjjtsa.html) to secure the printer with a password.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your printer-properties, then select the security-tab.
You can specify there, which user has access to this printer.
You can then deny your children's account to print.

If you want to configure time-based printing, take a look at the advanced-tab.
There you can specify, at which time it is available.

**EDIT**: Maybe this is not possible on XP-home-editions. I don't have Windows XP to test it.
But if it is possible on your machine, your printer-properties schould look like this:

[image]